# My Program keeps seg faulting with overloaded operators

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, overloading, operator-keyword, bus-error

Header File

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

class MyInt
{
  friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const MyInt& myint);
  friend istream& operator>> (istream& in, MyInt& myint);
  friend istream& getline (istream& , MyInt& , char delim = '\n');

  friend MyInt operator+ (const MyInt& x, const MyInt& y);
  friend MyInt operator* (const MyInt& x, const MyInt& y);

  friend MyInt operator++(MyInt& x, int y);     //post-increment ++
  friend MyInt operator++(MyInt& x);            //pre-increment ++
  friend MyInt operator--(MyInt& x);            //pre-decrement --
  friend MyInt operator--(MyInt& x, int y);     //post-decrement --

  friend bool operator< (const MyInt& x, const MyInt& y);
  friend bool operator> (const MyInt& x, const MyInt& y);
  friend bool operator<=(const MyInt& x, const MyInt& y);
  friend bool operator>=(const MyInt& x, const MyInt& y);
  friend bool operator==(const MyInt& x, const MyInt& y);
  friend bool operator!=(const MyInt& x, const MyInt& y);
public:
  MyInt(int n=0);                           // default constructor
  MyInt(const char* number);               // c-style string with digits

  ~MyInt();                          // destructor

  MyInt(const MyInt& );           // copy constructor
  MyInt& operator=(const MyInt& );   // assignment operator
  //MyInt& operator+(const MyInt& x);
  //MyInt& operator*(const MyInt& x);
  int getLength() const;                // return int length



private:

  int current_size;
  int actual_number;
  int max_size;
  char * IntList;
};
```

Class Declaration

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <cstring>
    #include <cctype>
    #include "myint.h"
    using namespace std;

// friend functions (operatior overloads)

  ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const MyInt& myint){
        for(int i = 0; i < myint.current_size; i ++)
        {
                out << myint.IntList[i];
        }
        return out;
  }
  istream& operator >> (istream& in, MyInt& myint){
        int input;
        in >> input;
        cout << "Input: " << input << endl;
        int digits = 10;
        myint.current_size = 1;
        myint.IntList = new char[myint.current_size];
        myint.IntList[0] = '0';

        myint.actual_number = input;
        if(input >= 0 ){
                int length = 0;
                for(int x = input; x!=0; x /= 10)
                         length++;

                myint.current_size = length;
                for(int i = 0; i < length-2; i++)
                        digits *= 10;
                myint.IntList = new char[myint.current_size];

                myint.IntList[0] = '0' + (input/digits);
                for(int i = length-1; i > 0; i--){
                        myint.IntList[i] = '0' + (input % 10);
                        input/=10;
                }


        }

        return in;
  }


  MyInt::MyInt(int n){
        actual_number = 0;
        int digits = 10;
        current_size = 1;
        IntList = new char[current_size];
        IntList[0] = '0';

        if(n >= 0 ){
                actual_number = n;
                int length = 0;
                for(int x = n; x!=0; x /= 10)
                         length++;

                current_size = length;
                for(int i = 0; i < length-2; i++)
                        digits *= 10;
                IntList = new char[current_size];

                IntList[0] = '0' + (n/digits);
                for(int i = length-1; i > 0; i--){
                        IntList[i] = '0' + (n % 10);
                        n/=10;
                }


        }


  }

  MyInt::MyInt(const char* num){            // conversion from c-string

        current_size = strlen(num);
        IntList = new char[current_size];
        int count = 0;
        int size = 0;
        int j = 0;
        while(isdigit(num[j])){
                count++;
                j++;
        }
       for(int i = 0; i <count; i++)
                IntList[i] = num[i];
       sscanf(IntList, "%d", actual_number);
  }

  MyInt::~MyInt(){

        delete [] IntList;              //deallocate memory
  }

  MyInt::MyInt(const MyInt& copy_int){
        max_size = copy_int.max_size;
        current_size = copy_int.current_size;


        for(int i = 0; i < current_size; i++)
                IntList[i] = copy_int.IntList[i];
  }

   MyInt operator+ (const MyInt& x, const MyInt& y){
        cout << "Adding Ints: " << endl;
        MyInt r;
        r.actual_number = y.actual_number + x.actual_number;
        return r;
  }
  MyInt operator* (const MyInt& x, const MyInt& y){
        cout << "Multiplying Ints: " << endl;
        MyInt r;
        r.actual_number = y.actual_number * x.actual_number;
        return r;

   }

  bool operator< (const MyInt& x, const MyInt& y){
        if(x.actual_number < y.actual_number)
                return true;
        else
                return false;
  }
  bool operator> (const MyInt& x, const MyInt& y){
        cout << "x: " << x.actual_number << "y:" << y.actual_number << endl;
        if(x.actual_number > y.actual_number)
                return true;
        else
                return false;
  }
  bool operator<= (const MyInt& x, const MyInt& y){
        if(x.actual_number <= y.actual_number)
                return true;
        else
                return false;
  }
  bool operator>= (const MyInt& x, const MyInt& y){
        if(x.actual_number >= y.actual_number)
                return true;
        else
                return false;
  }
  bool operator==(const MyInt& x, const MyInt& y){
        if(x.actual_number == y.actual_number)
                return true;
        else
                return false;
  }
  bool operator!=(const MyInt& x, const MyInt& y){
        if(x.actual_number != y.actual_number)
                return true;
        else
                return false;
  }


 MyInt& MyInt::operator=(const MyInt& assign_int ){
        if(this != &assign_int)
        {    
                delete [] IntList;
                this->actual_number = assign_int.actual_number;
                cout << "actual num: " << this->actual_number << endl;

                int digits = 10;
                current_size = 1;
                IntList = new char[current_size];
                IntList[0] = '0';

                if(actual_number >= 0 ){
                        int length = 0;
                        for(int x = actual_number; x!=0; x /= 10)
                                length++;

                        current_size = length;
                        for(int i = 0; i < length-2; i++)
                                digits *= 10;
                        IntList = new char[current_size];

                        IntList[0] = '0' + (actual_number/digits);
                        for(int i = length-1; i > 0; i--){
                                IntList[i] = '0' + (actual_number % 10);
                                actual_number/=10;
                        }
                }

        }
        return *this;

  }
```

The problem is with my overloaded + and * operators. I've tried everything I could think of. The error I get is either Segmentation Fault (core dumped) or Bus Error (core dumped). I know it must just be something I'm not seeing and any help is appreciated!! Thank you!

Comment: Your copy-constructor doesn't allocate memory for `IntList`.

Comment: So I made my copy constructor almost identical to my overloaded = operator and I still have this problem.

Comment: @HarrisonHarward Why not save yourself from all of these headaches and use `std::vector<int>` instead of `int *`.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason you're seeing problems with your overloaded `operator+()` and `operator*()` is that they return by value.

Returning by value means creating a copy of whatever is returned.  That copy will be returned to the caller and (normally) destructed eventually.

The actual problem is then in your copy constructor

```
MyInt::MyInt(const MyInt& copy_int){
    max_size = copy_int.max_size;
    current_size = copy_int.current_size;


    for(int i = 0; i < current_size; i++)
            IntList[i] = copy_int.IntList[i];
}
```

which does not initialise `IntList` to point at anything, before assigning to `IntList[i]` in the loop.   The result of doing that is undefined behaviour.

Since the value returned by your functions will eventually cease to exist, its destructor will be invoked.

```
MyInt::~MyInt(){

    delete [] IntList;              //deallocate memory
}
```

which, also because `IntList` has not been initialised causes undefined behaviour.

Big Hint:  both your other constructors have a statement `IntList = new char[current_size];`.   Logic might suggest the copy constructor needs something similar.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm looking into that now!

Comment: I added the line to allocated the memory for IntList and I'm still getting the seg fault.

Comment: You need to look at all of your functions to see if they behave consistently.  For example, your constructor that accepts an `int` allocates `IntList` twice, but doesn't copy data (e.g. from the first allocated block to the second) and doesn't release it either.   The `operator>>()` does something similar.   This is probably a result of you copying faulty code into multiple places - and means you have the same problem replicated several times.    You're going to have to work through that on your own - a Q&A format is not suitable for debugging code with multiple problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

Allocate the memory to `IntList` in your copy constructor.

```
MyInt::MyInt(const MyInt& copy_int){
    max_size = copy_int.max_size;
    current_size = copy_int.current_size;

    for(int i = 0; i < current_size; i++)
            IntList[i] = copy_int.IntList[i];
}
```

Your code in `operator+` and `operator*` is creating a new object `r` whose members are not properly initialised, and also in your copy constructor members are not properly copied.

Comment: I added the line to allocated the memory for IntList and I'm still getting the seg fault.